# A problem regarding triangle law.

Tags: vectors

Recently, I started learning vector but I got stuck to the triangle law, my teacher says that triangle law is a truth which we have to accept without any arguments against it.

Is there any intuition behind  triangle law of vector addition.

Pls help me....

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: There are multiple ways to prove this, and it all depends on which field of math the proof uses. For example, you might not accept the fact that a vector is still the same after you translate it, so you might not accept the 'tip-to-tail' definition. However, [here](https://www.mathstopia.net/vectors/triangle-law-vector-addition) is one way by using trigonometry.

Comment: Thanks, But the article you referred didn't answered my question

Comment: Maybe a real-life interpretation can help you understand it. If I walk 3 metres north and then walk 4 metres west, can you determine my total displacement? This is analogous to $\begin{pmatrix}{3}\\{0}\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}{0}\\{-4}\end{pmatrix}$. Of course, my total displacement vector is the hypotenuse of the triangle.

Comment: Yes..I tried it many times.

Answer (score 3):

Every vector can be represented by a horizontal and vertical component. For the sum of two vectors, if we add their vertical components and then their horizontal components together, we get an identical resultant vector as placing them end to end. The resultant vector being the line joining the two ends which makes a triangle.